# getting the text between the first and second occurence of a sequence

Tags: regex

How can I get the text between the first and second occurence of a sequence while including the first occurence and excluding the second occurence?

So for example:

Let my sequence be = `"xx - "`
Let my text be = `"xx - blablabla bla blaxx - blablabla bla bla xx - blabla"`

So i want my regular expression to get this chunk:

```
"xx - blablabla bla bla"
```

I tried something like this:

```
^xx - .*xx -
```

but this gets the text between the first and third occurence, and does not exclude the last occurence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(xx - )(.*?)\1
```

Explanation

```
(xx - )     # your sequence (group 1)
(.*?)       # anything, match non-greedily into group 2
\1          # whatever group 1 was
```

You want the contents of group 2.

Be aware that regex engines use different styles of back-referencing, the most common alternative to `\1` is `$1`.

---

Here's why your approach does not work: Your error is extremely common. It consists of thinking that `.*` somehow magically would stop at the right point to let the rest of the regex match. It does not.

`.*` goes right to the end of the line/string, without any amount of consideration. That's called *"greedy matching"*. When it hit the end of the string, backtracking occurs. The first point where the rest of your regex can match is the last occurrence of your sequence, *seen from the end of the string*. You end up with the longest possible match.

`.*?` does what's called *"non-greedy matching"*. It checks the rest of the regex before it moves to the next character. That's why the first occurrence of your sequence can match. You end up with the shortest possible match.

Comment: The tricky part here is that he wants the first delimiter as well.  I've not been able to come up with a regex that will do it. The closest I've come is: `(xx - ).*?(?=\1)` which returns 2 matches. And even then it won't work if there's no second delimiter in the string.

Comment: @Talljoe: As if you could not concatenate the results of group 1 and group 2 after the match. ;-) One can make things much more complicated than they are…

Comment: @Tomalak, true.  Was trying to find a singular solution, though. Concat might not be available here.

Comment: @Talljoe: `((xx - ).*?)\2` and the contents of group 1.

Comment: @Tomalak, that's what I originally wrote in my answer (which I deleted because yours had more explanation).  As a purely academic exercise I was trying to find a solution that only matched the requested string and worked with or without the second delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your language,

```
>> string="xx - blablabla bla blaxx - blablabla bla bla xx - blabla"
=> "xx - blablabla bla blaxx - blablabla bla bla xx - blabla"
>> string.split("xx -")[1]
=> " blablabla bla bla"
>> "xx -" + string.split("xx -")[1]
=> "xx - blablabla bla bla"
>>
```

do a split on "xx -". The item you want is always at the 2nd position, ie index 1. Add back "xx -" to get your final string. No need too much regex.